# Как протестировать платную тему Вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Никогда не пользовался платными темами Вордпресс. Удалось получить 3 платных темы вордпресс **бесплатно**. Тема может быть использована я так понял только один раз на одном домене. А как мне ее протестировать предварительно на тестовом домене, чтобы потом использовать на реальном сайте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего, если вы получили платные темы бесплатно, убедитесь, что это не так называемые nulled темы (со сломанной защитой). Такие темы могут содержать вирусы и бэкдоры.

Реального механизма проверки числа установок платной темы не существует. Никогда не встречал такого на практике. Так что можете ставить на любое количество доменов. Теоретически (но весьма вряд ли) можете получить юридические претензии.

Если уж совсем параноидально подходить к вопросу - вам никто не мешает создать 100,500 доменов на локальной машине, которые не видны из Интернет (записи в файле hosts в Windows, например) и тестировать темы сколько душе угодно.

Comment: я на зануленной теме создал 3 сайта на 1000 долларов. теперь хочу на официальной.

Comment: .... И что? ....

Comment: впрочем, я приму ваш ответ к сведению, так как не люблю ВП и создал поэтому свою CMS, но раз уж пришлось и на ВП делать  - поэтому пришлось поинтересоваться данным аспектам. Платные темы бесплатно предложил мне сам офиц. сайт Envato Market,  я их скачал и не знаю что с ними делать. )) У меня зануленная Avada - зануленная профессионально, без вирусов и бэкдоров. просто супер